# Datatables JQuery - Filter rows based on value in JSON

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I know this question has been asked several times but I have tried each of the solutions and it does not work for me.

I have the next script:

```
 var table = $('.dataTable').DataTable( {
    "dom": 'tip',
    "lengthMenu": [20],
    "ajax": 'myUrl',
    "sAjaxDataProp":"",
    "columns" : [
        {"data" : "data.employee_num"},
        {"data" : "data.name"},
        {"data" : "data.user"},
        {"data" :
            function(row){
                return row.data.food!== "1" ? "Yes" : "No";
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

The JSON structure is something like this:

```
[
    {
        "data": {
            "employee_num": "X",
            "name": "XXXX",
            "user": "XXXX",
            "status ": "X",
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "employee_num": "Y",
            "name": "YYYY",
            "user": "YYYY",
            "status ": "Y",
        }
    }
]
```

It works fine, but i need to filter some rows depending of a certain value. For example, in the JSON I have `data.status` and it can be 1 or 2. What i need is if the raw have a status of 2, all the row must be removed. I tried using `filter()` and `rows.remove();` and both of them didnt work (or at least i dont know if i did it correctly)

How I can achieve this?

Comment: Please add the code where you are parsing the JSON data. This code only shows the setup.

Comment: I cant do that because i work in an hospital and the data nor structure can be displayed. i had to change it a lil bit so i can post the question :/

Comment: The data is understandable but you could mock something. Not being able to post the data structure is a bit silly. People don't need specifics to help. Just explain the flow better with sudo code if needed.

Comment: Ok, i alredy updated the question

Comment: I still don't see what I am expecting. But somewhere, you will parse the data and you will stay that you instance of `DataTables()`, looks like `table`, will remove the row. That is what you would call remove on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so this is the way to remove rows depending on a value (the correct way):

```
var table = $('.dataTable').DataTable( {
    "dom": 'tip',
    "lengthMenu": [20],
    "ajax": 'myUrl',
    "sAjaxDataProp":"",
    "columns" : [
        {"data" : "data.employee_num"},
        {"data" : "data.name"},
        {"data" : "data.user"},
        {"data" :
            function(row){
                return row.data.food!== "1" ? "Yes" : "No";
            }
        }
    ],
    // Answer 
    "createdRow": function( row, data ) {
        if (data["data"]["status"] === "2" ) {
            table.row(row).remove().draw();
        }
    }
});
```